# Find the side of the square.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, contest-math

The problem I am proposing to solve was posed in a math contest for students of 17-18 years old, this month.

With the data in the picture, find the side of the square.

[image]

I did find the solution but it involves a long way across calculating the combined length of the red segments (not drawn in the original problem) and minimizing it for points on the segment of length $1$. With the diagonal we can get the side. I think there is a better and quicker way to solve it. I bring it here, maybe somebody could find this solution.

Comment: Does the red "line" mean anything?

Comment: Not sure the labels are clear.  does the "$1$" refer to one leg of the small right triangle (which would then have hypotenuse $\sqrt 5$) or does the $1$ refer to the longer segment which connects the two right angled vertices of your two triangles?  If the latter, then what does the red "line" signify?

Comment: @Arthur. The red line means nothing ("not drawn in the original problem") but my try to solve it, as mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just a simple pythagoras theorem. You find the diagonal of the square $=\sqrt {50}$
Therefore the side of the square is $=5$
[image]

Comment: Do you mean diagonal of the square instead of diameter of the square @Seyed?

Comment: @Dbchatto67, You are right, I fixed it. Thank you

Comment: When rendering a square root, place braces around the argument to get the radical sign to cover all characters.  Thus \sqrt{50} properly gives $\sqrt{50}$.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the red line means nothing, and $1$ is the length of the gray segment between the $2$ segment and the $5$ segment:

Turn the square (almost) $45^\circ$ around, so that the $5$ segment becomes horizontal, and place the corner of the square where the $5$ segment starts at the origin. The opposite corner of the square will be at $(7, 1)$.

What is the length of the diagonal of the square? Then what is its side length?

Answer (score 4):

Rotate the square so that the $5$ and $2$ segments are horizontal:

[image]

Label the left most corner as $(0,0)$. Now hopefully you can see that the right most corner is at $(7,1)$.

From this, we can calculate the distance from the left most to the right most as

\begin{align}d^2&=7^2+1^2\\
&=49+1\\
&=50\\
d&=\sqrt{50}\end{align}

Now we can calculate the side length of the square as we know its diagonal length

\begin{align}s^2+s^2&=d^2\\
2s^2&=\sqrt{50}^2\\
2s^2&=50\\
s^2&=25\\
s&=\sqrt{25}\\
s&=5\end{align}