# Primary school competition problem find the area of a square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, contest-math, area

Someone posted online a primary school competition problem. I solved it using the Cayley-Menger determinant (finding the answer is 169/2 after getting the length of AD being 13) but it probably isn't the intended solution. I cannot find a "primary school" way to solve it. The problem is to find the area of the square given the following:

[image]

The angles $\angle ABC=90^o,\angle BCD=90^o$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157955/find-the-side-of-the-square/3157969#3157969

Comment: @Seyed Ah thanks almost the same question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the Pythagorean theorem (the diagram can be rotated such that the interior segments are all horizontal/vertical), the diagonal $DA$ has length $\sqrt{12^2+5^2}=13$, so the square side length is $\frac{13}{\sqrt2}$ and the area $\frac{169}2$.

Comment: Ah thanks so simple.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157955/find-the-side-of-the-square/3157969#3157969

Comment: This is confusing, when you say "new [coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system)", I'm thinking; Polar, Spherical, etc, but you mean change $C$ coordinates?

Comment: @NatalieBurke Just rotate it all...